# c# HtmlAgilityPack select main nodes

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to figure out how can i select only main nodes from a loaded HTML document as the following example:

```
<div id="main">
  <p>paragraph 1</p>
  <p>paragraph 2</p>
  <img src="exzample.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="main2">
  <div>some text</div>
  <p>some text</p>
  <img src="exzample.jpg" />
</div>
<p class="a_class">
  <div>some text</div>
  <span>some text</span>
</p>
```

I know I can iterate over all elements but in my case, I just need to get only the 3 blocks (in this example) from the loaded html. I do not know how can I select such nodes using SelectNodes function or any other function.

I'm using HtmlAgilityPack library.

**Note**: Main nodes can be any html tag (div, p, span and so on...)

Comment: By main nodes, you mean, the `div` with id `main`, `div` with id `main2`, and `p` with class `a_class`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/*` will select all immediate descendats of the root node (which the document posted in this question is lacking).